# EXT JS : No output from console

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, web-applications, extjs

I am developing a very simple web application using the `EXT JS` framework. Usually I can tell when there is an issue because it will give some kind of error notification in the `console` output in either Firefox's `FireBug` or Chrome's `Inspect Element`. However, now when I load my web app, nothing is rendered to the screen and there is no `console` output to give me some guidance as to what went wrong.

What are some general steps I can take to find the source of the problem, in the absence of the `console` log?

Comment: make sure you're using debug version of Ext.JS, also not every javascript error causes a console log. Also maybe there's no error but something is hiding your html; for example a white overlay or your container element's height is somehow 0px.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. EXT JS does not seem to have a debugger in itself. Do you mean use the built-in debugger provided in Firebug or Inspect Element? If so, is there a "main entrance" that I should put the first breakpoint? Like I would in gdb?

Comment: like many other frameworks, ext js has two different versions, one is debug version which contains code that adds descriptive messages to the console to help you, and the other is minified, has no debug code and used for production. [This](http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.0-gpl/ext-all.js) is the minified version, and [this](http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.0-gpl/ext-all-debug.js) is the debug version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check all file paths in Ext.define.

Comment: After all my looking into debugging and using console debugger, ended up being an issue with file paths. Thanks!